# check if contract address is token (get token information like symbol)

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

is it possible through web3 to get token information like symbol and total supply like the etherscan API pro endpoint tokeninformation when providing the contract address?

I want to check if the addresses I collect are tokens or just normal contracts.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a general token (ERC-20, ERC-721, ...) ABI JSON interface into your web3 instance when loading the contract data. Then you can try calling the functions and see if they return value or fail.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html

```
const contract = new Contract(jsonInterface, address);

try {
    const symbol = await contract.methods.symbol().call();
} catch (e) {
    // does not have the `symbol` function or public property
}
```

Mind that some token standards (such as ERC-721) don't require a contract to contain a `name` and `symbol` fields.

Comment: thank you. Yes right now its only working with erc20, did not have the time yet to read up on the 721 standard as Im few days into the whole topic.